# Accuracy goes down during epoch keras

Tags: neural-network, python-3.5, keras, floating-accuracy, loss

I've tried to write a neural network but the accuracy doesn't change each epoch. I'm using keras and I can watch the accuracy change as each epoch is evaluated per se and it will start low, go up a bit, then drop back down to the exact same value each time [example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ONj9.png). I've tried changing the batch size, learning rates, changing the data around a bit, but every time it does the same thing, just perhaps with a different accuracy value. I've also tried different optimizers. Any help is appreciated. (Also I was able to get an mnist example working)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=100, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(history), init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(lr=1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=50, verbose = 1)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have a single neuron in your output layer, I assume you're doing regression and not classification.

If that's the case, then you should change your loss function to `'mse'` and you also should remove the activation in your output layer because the sigmoid function will squash your output between 0 and 1.